# Pegar o valor de nome e da data (usando datepicker), e depois calcular utilizando somente (JQUERY),

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```js
 $(function () {
                
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                   
                });
                
            });
```

```html
    <body>
        <form id="formu">
            Nome:
            <input type="text" id="name"><br>
            Data de nascimento:          
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="data"/><br>
            <input type="button" id="botton" value="Ok">            
        </form>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
    </body>
```

** a idade do usuario. Em seguida mostrar na div resultado.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var esteAno = new Date().getFullYear();
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  onSelect: function(date) {
    var ano = date.split('-')[2]; // ano aqui
    var anos = esteAno - ano;
    $('#resultado').html('');
    var strAnos = 'anos';
    if(anos === 1) {
        strAnos = 'ano';
    }
    $('#resultado').html($('#name').val() +' você tem ' +anos+ ' ' +strAnos);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<form id="formu">
        Nome:
        <input type="text" id="name"><br>
        Data de nascimento:          
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="data"/><br>
        <input type="button" id="botton" value="Ok">            
    </form>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: So uma duvida `onSelect: function(date) { `  é para executar esta função a partir do momento que o usuário selecionar a data isto?

Comment: Yap, a partir do momento em que clica/pressiona uma data @user49744

Comment: Para que significa nesta parte do codigo:    `date.split('-')[2];`    ?

Comment: Dividimos a data pelo '-' e vamos buscar o ultimo do conjunto (array) @user49744.

Comment: E porque vc colocou  `$('#resultado').html('');` ?

Comment: Para inserir na div `#resultado`